# Why Is 4.0.3 fastest version on android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I have HAXM installed successfully, but even using HAXM on later Android OS versions It just isn't as snappy as 4.0.3. Has anyone else noticed this? What is it about 4.0.3 that makes that version so snappy on the android emulator with HAXM?

Comment: Most likely, it is because Android itself is getting more complex.

Comment: I'm with CommonsWare, have you tried it on older versions than 4.0.3?

Comment: Yes, but I just realized, although HAXM is working on my 2.3.3 emulator, "Use Host GPU" doesn't work with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CommonsWare pointed out this is likely because of increasing complexity of Android. I had thought that this couldn't be the answer because my 2.3.3 emulator was still slower than my 4.0.3 emulator, but as discovered [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html), to use graphics acceleration "Use Host GPU", you must have an emulator with at least API 15 (4.0.3):

> Start the AVD Manager and create a new AVD with the **Target** value of
>   **Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15)**, revision 3 or higher.

Therefore 4.0.3 would be the "least complex" version of android that also has gpu acceleration capabilities.